# Which SMTP servers support implicit SSL?

Tags: email, ssl, smtp

We're working on a COTS product that includes e-mail integration and would like to test with several smtp servers.  Which ones accept implicit SSL connections?

Comment: you might want to specify the direction.  The reasson I say this is that exim will support it as a client (meaning it can be configured to use implicit TLS (or smtps, or tls-on-connect as Exim calls it)) but cannot be configures to accept implicit TLS (it will handle STARTTLS only).  This might change but the theory seemed to be that Exim should support it as a client because there are stupid servers that can only accept mail that way, but Exim shouldn't _be_ one of those stupid servers and should use the official standard.

Comment: @jj33, good point, I updated my question.  I'm looking for an smtp server that accepts implicit ssl connections to test my app that is initiating them.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's a good chart you could use as reference on wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_mail_servers

See the columns "SMTP over TLS" and "SSL" columns.  It's not exactly clear but I think you're looking for ones with "Yes" in the "SSL" column.

Comment: On further review, it is really not clear.  "SSL" could refer to SSL anywhere including SSL for Webmail, doesn't necessarily mean SMTP over SSL.  Likewise, SMTP over TLS is more likely to mean implicit and not explicit.

Comment: Good point.  I was kind of thinking "SMTP over TLS" was STARTTLS and "SSL" was tls-on-connect (because people often confuse TLS and SSL w/ upwardly negotiated connections and negotiated-at-connect connections, respectively) but you make a good point that based on other features it's not clear.  I will say that Exim is _only_ an MTA and it has a "Yes" in both columns, implying SSL isn't HTTPS.  Hopefully it's at least useful as a starting point

Comment: yes, it's a great list and a good starting point, but seems to not directly answer the question.  I did vote you +1 though.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect any servers that support SSL/TLS connections to support SSL only connections.  If the server is listening on the the SSMTP port (465), this port is listening it should support only SSL/TLS connections.

Servers should not be SSL/TLS only on the SMTP port (25).  The SMTP protocol is not SSL/TLS only.  The protocol has been enhanced to support StartTLS functionality.  Requiring TLS/SSL would severely limit the server's ability to accept email.

I would expect most servers listening on the Submission port (587) to require a switch to SSL/TLS before enabling authentication.  This port should require authentication or a local connection before accepting messages.